# Resize add ons picture on jumbotron using bootstrap

Tags: css, image, resize

Can somebody help me, I wanna build my portfolio web, but in this case, I wanna show my photo on jumbotron using bootstrap, you can see my sample below: https://i.stack.imgur.com/W8xFE.jpg

can I resize the photo, if this can, how?
here my code

```html
<div id="carouselExampleSlidesOnly" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
            <img src="img/01.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
            <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                <h1 class="display-4">About Me</h1>
                <img src="img/user.png" id="profile">
                <h2>TEXT HERE</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

```css
/*jumbotron*/
.jumbotron{
    /*background-image: url(../img/01.jpg);*/
    background-size: cover;
    text-align: center;
    height: 760px;
    color: #fff;
    margin-top: -20px;
}

.display-4{
    margin-top: 150px; 
}

/*slider*/
.carousel-item img{
    background-size: cover;
    display: flex;
    height: 100vh;
}

.carousel-item h1{
    margin-top: -550px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 40px ;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.carousel-item p{
    /*margin-top: -550px;*/
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 36px ;
    font-weight: unset;
}
```

```html
<div id="carouselExampleSlidesOnly" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
            <img src="img/01.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
            <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                <h1 class="display-4">About Me</h1>
                <img src="img/user.png" id="profile">
                <h2>TEXT HERE</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of this part of code, all the images inside carousel-item will have 100vh height:

```
.carousel-item img{
    background-size: cover;
    display: flex;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

so you should just select the one you want. you can write this styles:

```
.carousel-item > img{
    background-size: cover;
    display: flex;
    height: 100vh;
}



 .carousel-caption img{
  width: 200px; /* whatever you want*/
}
```

Comment: thx bro,its work,but fyi,carousel-item class for backround jumbotron,not insert photo on jumbotron,thats different,but thank u it's work